powershell update folder security upto a certain folder that is at unknown depth
I am trying to update folder permission to folders until it reaches certain folder
Once those folders is found it will need to stop and go to the next folder inside the subfolder inside.For example c:\test\ will have 20 subfolders and inside those folders might be 20 more where one of the folder is called admin and that has subfolders inside it.
I would like it to change the permission to the all the folders until it reaches c:\test\1.....\admin then goto c:\test\2\ without changing the permission of the folders inside the admin folder.
Here is what my code is currently
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\100-LAN LLP" -Recurse -Directory
$Folders2 = Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\300-EE" -Recurse -Directory
$Folders3 = Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\400-House_Insp" -Recurse -Directory
$Folders4 = Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\500-AR" -Recurse -Directory
$Folders5 = Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\600-SP" -Recurse -Directory
$Folders6 = Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\800-Survey" -Recurse -Directory
$Folders7 = Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\900-VR" -Recurse -Directory
$Folders8 = Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\200-AE" -Recurse -Directory

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("LANNJ\Domain Users","Modify","deny")
$AccessRule2 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("LANNJ\Domain Users","Read","Allow")
$AccessRule3 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("LANNJ\Domain Users","write","deny")

foreach($folder8 in $Folders8)
{
   $folder8.FullName

  if($folder8.name -eq "Admin" -or $folder.Name -eq "Cad" -or $folder.name -eq "20000-AE" -or $folder.name -like "proposals")
 {
    write-host $folder.name " was found"
    break
 }
    $acl = get-acl $folder.FullName 
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($AccessRule)
    $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule2)
    $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule3)
    $acl | Set-Acl $folder8.FullName
    get-acl $folder8.FullName | fl
}

I tried using nested loop but it continues going to folders inside the folders inside the admin ect.
I tried getting the depth number of the search folder and changing the folder position in negative but it did not work.

The break will exit the foreach loop so after first folder in the IF is found the code stops.

yeah but it will not go to the next subfolder so it goes to c:\test\2 instead of c:\test\1\a

You are recursively getting all folders and then only omitting if the name equals any of those terms. Any subfolders that have been found under those omitted folders will still be used because you are not explicitly omitting them like "Admin", "Cad", etc.
Here is a one way to to recursively get folders while ignoring folders with certain names and their subfolders

function Get-FolderWithExclusions {
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        $Path,
        [Parameter()]
        [string[]]
        $FoldersToExclude,
        [Parameter()]
        [string[]]
        $KeywordsToExclude
    )

    $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory | Where-Object {
        $folder = $_
        $folder.BaseName -NotIn $FoldersToExclude -and
        !(($KeywordsToExclude | ForEach-Object {
                    $folder.BaseName -match $_
                }) -contains $true)
    }
    $folders
    $folders | ForEach-Object { 
        Get-FolderWithExclusions -Path $_ -FoldersToExclude $FoldersToExclude -KeywordsToExclude $KeywordsToExclude
    }
}

$omitFolders = 'Admin', 'Cad', '20000-AE'
$omitKeywords = 'proposals'

$Folders = Get-FolderWithExclusions -Path 'P:\100-LAN LLP' -FoldersToExclude $omitFolders -KeywordsToExclude $omitKeywords
$Folders2 = Get-FolderWithExclusions -Path 'P:\300-EE' -FoldersToExclude $omitFolders -KeywordsToExclude $omitKeywords
$Folders3 = Get-FolderWithExclusions -Path 'P:\400-House_Insp' -FoldersToExclude $omitFolders -KeywordsToExclude $omitKeywords
$Folders4 = Get-FolderWithExclusions -Path 'P:\500-AR' -FoldersToExclude $omitFolders -KeywordsToExclude $omitKeywords
$Folders5 = Get-FolderWithExclusions -Path 'P:\600-SP' -FoldersToExclude $omitFolders -KeywordsToExclude $omitKeywords
$Folders6 = Get-FolderWithExclusions -Path 'P:\800-Survey' -FoldersToExclude $omitFolders -KeywordsToExclude $omitKeywords
$Folders7 = Get-FolderWithExclusions -Path 'P:\900-VR' -FoldersToExclude $omitFolders -KeywordsToExclude $omitKeywords
$Folders8 = Get-FolderWithExclusions -Path 'P:\200-AE' -FoldersToExclude $omitFolders -KeywordsToExclude $omitKeywords

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('LANNJ\Domain Users', 'Modify', 'deny')
$AccessRule2 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('LANNJ\Domain Users', 'Read', 'Allow')
$AccessRule3 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('LANNJ\Domain Users', 'write', 'deny')

foreach ($folder8 in $Folders8) {
    $folder8.FullName

    $acl = Get-Acl $folder.FullName 
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($AccessRule)
    $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule2)
    $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule3)
    $acl | Set-Acl $folder8.FullName
    Get-Acl $folder8.FullName | Format-List
}


Ill try this thank you

The thing is I don't know the names of the folder under admin or cad. Does that matter?

If you specify "Admin" as a folder to omit then it will not include folder called "Admin" or any of it's subfolders

I tested and it still shows admin. If I don't do recursive search it doesn't get the subfolders inside the subfolders inside the main folder

Get-FolderWithExclusion is recursive and will get the subfolders and it will omit any foldernames you specify for -FoldersToExclude parameter and their subfolders.  I think you misunderstand how to use this in the context of your existing script.  I will update a little later when I get a moment.

When I try that one it gives me an error where it tries to read inside my c:\windows\system32 folder for some reason

Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Test1' because it does not exist. At line:10 char:16

I got it skip Admin and it subfolders like this $folder8 = 'F:\Test' $omit = 'Admin' $omit2 = 'Cad' $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder8 -Directory -Recurse | where-object {($_.FullName -inotmatch $omit -and $_.PsIsContainer)} |select-object fullname foreach($folder in $folders) {     $folder.fullname }  but it will not allow me to omit both

Updated answer for the context of your script

I was able to get it work
$omit = 'Admin'
$omit2 = 'Cad'
$folderTest = 'F:\Test'
$folders2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderTest -Directory -Recurse | where-object {($_.FullName -inotmatch $omit2 -and $_.PsIsContainer) -and ($_.FullName -inotmatch $omit -and $_.PsIsContainer)} 

foreach($folder in $folders2)
{
   $folder.fullname
}



Nice.  You don't need the -and $_.PsIsContainer in the where filters since you are already only getting directories from Get-ChildItem using -Directory switch.  Also, note that this will also omit folders and their subfolders that are partial matches like "F:\Test\Academy" and "F:\Test\Adminicular"
